# Control links2 by python

Tags: python, controls, hyperlink

Is there any way to control links browser from python?
I need to make some bot, twill don't work on my page, Selenium need's X server.
Maybe other way to do it?

Comment: It might be easier to use a library. Tell us what exactly you need the bot to be capable of (e.g. javascript? forms?).

Answer (score 1):

Using X virtual framebuffer Xvfb you can run selenium/web browser without X:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1152x864x16
DISPLAY=1 ./firefox
```

and run the selenium tests from command line.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) (on Unix-like systems; [wexpect](http://code.google.com/p/wexpect/downloads/list) on Windows), just as I would for the purpose of controlling other text-based, interactive applications that don't offer an explicit API of their own.